# Polish gus and play framework java soap method not allowed

Tags: java, soap, playframework

I have a problem with Polish GUS api. My class is:

```
public SOAPMessage signInToGus() {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();

    SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
    QName toQname = new QName(RegonConstantsRepository.BASE_WSDL_ADDRESS, "To", "wsa");
    SOAPHeaderElement toElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(toQname);
    QName actionQname =  new QName(UrlRepository.signInUrl, "Action", "wsa");
    SOAPHeaderElement actionElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(actionQname);

    soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ns", "Zaloguj");
    SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement userKey = soapBody.addChildElement(
                    "ns", "pKluczUzytkownika",
                    Play.application().configuration().getString("gus.apiKey")
            );

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.removeHeader("Accept");
    headers.removeHeader("Content-Type");
    headers.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xop+xml");
    soapMessage.saveChanges();
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    SOAPMessage connectionMessage = createSOAPRequest();

    SOAPMessage soapMessage = soapConnection.call(connectionMessage, RegonConstantsRepository.BASE_WSDL_URL);
    return soapMessage;
}
```

And I have a big problem. I can't connect with soap service. This request is:

```
405 Method not allowed.
```